# Magento - getting data from an order or invoice

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I'm trying to write a Magento (CE 1.4) extension to export order data once an order has been paid for. I’ve set up an observer that hooks in to the sales_order_invoice_save_after event, and that is working properly - my function gets executed when an invoice is generated. But I’m having trouble getting information about the order, such as the shipping address, billing address, items ordered, order total, etc.

This is my attempt:

```
class Lightbulb_Blastramp_Model_Observer {
    public function sendOrderToBlastramp(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
        $order = $invoice->getOrder();

        $shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
        $billing_address = $order->getBillingAddress();
        $items = $invoice->getAllItems();
        $total = $invoice->getGrandTotal();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I tried doing a print_r on all those variables, and ended up getting a lot of data back. Could someone point me in the right direction of getting the shipping address of an order?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many Magento objects are based on `Varien_Object`, which has a method called `getData()` to get just the usually interesting data of the object (excluding the tons of other, but mostly useless data).

With your code you could either go for all the data at once:

```
$shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
var_dump($shipping_address->getData());
```

or directly for specific single properties like this:

```
$shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
var_dump(
    $shipping_address->getFirstname(),
    $shipping_address->getLastname(),
    $shipping_address->getCity()
);
```

To understand how this works, I'd recommend to make yourself more familiar with the `Varien_Object` and read a bit about PHPs [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), like `__call()`, `__get()` and `__set()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `print_r($shipping_address->toArray());`